# How to debug visual studio connection to oracle database (ORA-1254 & ORA-12638)?

Tags: debugging, windows-7, oracle11g, installation, reverse-engineering

### Background

I am working a new job and trying to set up my local environment. At the moment, I cannot debug our web solutions on visual studio 2008 because I believe I did not configure oracle 11g correctly when I installed it (getting an ORA-1254-TNS: could not resolve identifier specified" error. TNS is not an issue because doing direct connect in the solution). So I am pretty sure I need to reconfigure or reinstall my local 11g oracle with the right installation parameters.

### Problem

All previous developers have left before I even came. Nothing is documented. I do, however, have access to one of the machines where a developer was working. I am trying to figure out what parameters this developer used when used oracle 11g 11.2.0 on their machine.

### Additional Details

There are at least 50 websites and most of them were written in visual studio 2008. So when I load the vs 2008 solutions, I need a way to connect to whatever servers they made for these websites (in order to debug a site).

I need to make sure my local development environment allows me to debug. So I am talking about software installation of Oracle 11g. It is a client side installation. This is because I need a way for my client 11g to be able to connect to whatever servers they have developed.I do not have access to the local database on their machine that they created (and I believe that was only used for local development of websites. They called it client1, but I don't know how the username or password).

### Edits

When I didn't have oracle 11g I got the following error:

1. `System.Exception: System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater`

So after installing the client, I then get the error:

1. `ORA-1254: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

Here is code for the connection settings:

```
      public static DataSet ExecuteQuery(string sql)
        {
            OracleConnection oraConnection = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
            OracleCommand oraCommand = new OracleCommand(sql, oraConnection);
            oraConnection.Open();
}
```

Here is the error message for the code above:

Exception Details: System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Source Error:

```
Line 391:            OracleConnection oraConnection = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
Line 392:            OracleCommand oraCommand = new OracleCommand(sql, oraConnection);
Line 393:            oraConnection.Open();
Line 394:
Line 395:            OracleDataAdapter oraAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(oraCommand);

Source File: c:\projects\websiteNew\App_Code\CatalogDB.cs    Line: 393 

Stack Trace: 


[OracleException (0x80131938): ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
]
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException.Check(OciErrorHandle errorHandle, Int32 rc) +310694
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection.OpenOnLocalTransaction(String userName, String password, String serverName, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean unicode, Boolean omitOracleConnectionName) +683
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection..ctor(OracleConnectionString connectionOptions) +133
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) +40
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +29
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +433
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +72
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +457
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +100
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +116
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open() +40
   Catalog.CatalogDB.ExecuteQuery(String sql) in c:\projects\websiteNew\App_Code\CatalogDB.cs:393
   Catalog.CatalogDB.GetCompanyInfo(String portal_id) in c:\projects\websiteNew\App_Code\CatalogDB.cs:367
   Global.CompanyInfo() in c:\projects\websiteNew\App_Code\Global.asax.cs:69
   Global.Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\projects\websiteNew\App_Code\Global.asax.cs:55
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.RaiseOnStart(EventArgs e) +8878884
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.CompleteAcquireState() +237
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +504
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +66
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Here is the connection string. I edited it to have fake names/passwords/etc for security:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="ConnectionString"/>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ZARDOZ;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=fake1;Password= f8k3r;Unicode=True" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
    <add name="ZARDOZPubsConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ZARDOZ-DB2.were.not.in.oz;Initial Catalog=COMM2000;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=fake2;Password=f8k3r" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://were.not.in.oz/DC=were,DC=not,DC=in,DC=oz"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

### Edit

I have determined that the previous devs' are using tnsnames, put they were in ~/network/admin/ directory. I changed my *.ora files to look like theirs. I am now getting the following error:

```
ORA-12638: Credential retrieval failed
```

I will give upvotes to whoever comments and helps me fix this. I need to be able to debug code so that I can do my job, at the moment, I can't do that. :(

Thanks, 
GeekyOmega

Comment: Are you talking about the software installation (look for oraInventory), or the database creation (do you have access to the DB itself to query the current parameters), or both? Is it a server or client install; and if client, full or instant? Why do you need to reinstall rather than reconfigure?

Comment: @AlexPoole I updated my question to address your questions. I also provided additional information. Unfortunately, I do not have access to DB in order to query it.

Comment: If it is client-only then there are no data files, as there is no local database. How have you set up your connection/data source in Visual Studio - what driver, parameters, etc.? And how does that compare to the previous developer's settings? Not sure what "doing direct connect" means, but you said you aren't using a TNS alias, so the `.ora` files aren't relevant. Sounds like a connection config issue rather than a client installation issue. When you "load the vs 2008 solutions", do those contain the connection settings? Or are all 50 sites you're debugging connecting to the same dev/test DB?

Comment: The actual connection data used by the ex-developer will give more of a clue about what the issue might be. ORA-12154 could be a few things, depending on the naming method being used, but also the driver I think. Just a thought, are both PCs running the same version of Windows, and are they both either 32- or 64-bit?

Comment: @AlexPoole I have reason to believe all 50 sites are not connecting to the same dev/test DB. When I load vs 2008 solution, it contains the connection settings: web.config and catalogDB.cs file. When I try to debug the webpage, I get an ORA-1254 error. I confirmed both machines are running Windows 7 64-bit. I installed 32 bit version for my vs 2008 solution after it gave an error asking for it. Please let me know what information would be useful for you to help me debug this problem. I've been trying anything I can think of.

Comment: The connection settings - the driver and the connection string. They might show something wrong in how it's constructed. Maybe they refer to a server you can't see, or a hostname that you can't resolve to an IP, or the other dev did have a local database and you don't...

Comment: @AlexPoole I gave the code that is giving the error + stack trace. I can connect to the server/DB from my computer using sql developer. I can also debug EXACT same vs 2008 solution on the two old dev computers. So I don't think it is the connection string? I want to fix this issue so future coworkers can set up their own machines too.

Comment: Can you connect from SQL Developer with the exact same connection string? Still sounds like maybe a driver issue, but still don't know which driver you're using or what the connection string is. Does the log show the actual connection string it's really trying to use - just in case something odd is happening there. It's a 64-bit OS, VS is 32-bit from what you said, is the Oracle client 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: @AlexPoole I updated my answer to have the connection string you asked for. I can connect using to the DB using sql developer using the same connection string. How do I find the driver and log information you want? I am using Oracle 32-bit client.

Comment: I fixed the issue. It was related to .ora file and removing NTS to none for SQL authentification. The documentation caused me to work on this for a very long time. Thanks for your help Alex. :)

Comment: Great - perseverance paid off then. You should add what you had to do, and maybe some background from your investigation, as an answer.

Comment: @AlexPoole I just got back from a conference. I will do exactly that. Is there anyway I can contact you directly with dev questions in future? That is, do you have any experience with ASP.NET?

Comment: I have no experience with ASP.NET I'm afraid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly have you changed in *.ora files? Could you publish their current content? 
Try to play with this file: NETWORK\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora
I'd recommend to set

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)
```

If that won't help, then just try different values (but for me NONE worked perfectly).
Also check this one NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora you need record for your database there.

Also I experienced some difficulties when I had only x64 version of client. They were partially gone after I installed x86 version as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple explanation of what I did to fix the problem. The key was to look in the following directory NETWORK\ADMIN\:

1. tnsnames.ora 
   Added information that was present in the old dev machines. That is, we connected to two 
   databases
2. sqlnet.ora 
   As stated by another user here. It is essential that SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE = (NTS) is changed to SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE = (NONE).